# filtering the column value has more than 10000 list items in sharepoint 2013 rest api

Tags: rest, sharepoint-online

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$top=5000&$filter= ColumnName eq 'abc'"
```

Here ColumnName is indexed. And there are more than 10,000 records having value "abc" in ColumnName. I am getting the error:

> The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

How can I fix this error? I need the column to be filtered even if it has more than 10,000 or above list items in SharePoint online.

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue called list view threshold.  For Sharepoint online, we suggest you [index the column](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-index-to-a-sharepoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0) which you want to filter.

Below blog detailed explain about list view threshold, you may have a look:

- https://natechamberlain.com/2018/05/21/how-to-resolve-sharepoint-list-view-threshold-error-the-view-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-exceeds-the-list-view-threshold/
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#__throttlesandlimits&ID0EAABAAA=Online